# Search using single input while searching multiple tables

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I need to make a search button for ASP.NET C# web site. Making a button with 1 kind of search key is easy. For example:

```
Select * from table where name like '%' + search_criteria + '%'
```

But what I really need is to make a search button that will contain more "like" from different though tables. I have in my DB

1. Category.Category_Name nchar
2. Product.Description nchar
3. Product.Product_Cost float
4. Manufacturer.Manufacturer_Name nchar

And you can see which ones are in which table. Also with the help of GridView I want to show on my webpage only the first 3. But I want a single textBox with a single button and when I try to search something, search either category name or description or cost or manufaturer name all in 1.

I have read that you can only search multiple things from one table or use contain statement in order to search from different tables. I've looked many hour in internet but in vain. Can someone help me figure out what do I need to right in WHERE clause so I can put that in aspx.cs C# code in LIKE filter and have my button worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this exactly answers your question, but I will try. Although, to be fair, it is not supremely clear what you need and the question is bordering **Too Broad**

```
void btnSearch_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql = "select Product_name from Product p inner join Category c on p.Category_id = c.Category_id WHERE c.Category_Name Like '%{0}%' UNION ALL " +
        "select Product_name from Product where Description Like '%{0}%' UNION ALL " +
        "select Product_name from Product p inner join Manufacturer m on p.Manufacturer_id = m.Manufacturer_id WHERE m.Manufacturer_id Like '%{0}%' ";

    decimal price;
    if (decimal.TryParse(txtSearch.Text.Trim(), out price)
        sql +=   "UNION ALL select Product_name from Product where Product_Cost >= {0} " 
    Search(string.Format(sql, txtSearch.Text.Trim());
}


void Search (string sql)
{
    // use your sql here to fill the grid, etc.
}
```

**NOTE** @JoelCoehoorn noted about possibility of Sql Injection with this code [which is security concern]. I don't know if you care about it at this time. But to prevent Sql Injection you will need to use query parametrization. There will need to be slight change to the query but more changes to `Command` object setup.

Comment: What I wanted was to have one search bar (textbox) and a search button. If I write in it "AMD" then it will search all products that have AMD category name. If I write inside the box "View", it will bring me the product with the product name ViewSonic. And again if I write "40", it will bring me the products with price of 40 or 400 euros or something like that. I have seen how you can use the BETWEEN syntax inside the query for float but it is not mandatory to use it. I dont know if that helps you understand my question better. Im new to VS and proffessor asked us how it is done so thats why.

Comment: Thats why I am asking. Sorry for my english too:) Also from a previous exercise I had done with only one thing to search there is a place inside C# where you put the filter. Something like this: // add the LIKE filter
    strCommandText += " WHERE Description LIKE '%" + filterValue + "%'"; I wanted to know how you put all of the like clauses inside of where or generally how you write it in C#

Comment: As for the query I believe it will be easy to make it. Just bring all 4 tables and let the button do the job right?

Comment: @Orusthar Ok than. Check my updated answer. This should bring you more results from single text box and button

Comment: Thx! I will try it in a few hours (00:13 here:P)

Comment: This will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Tell me about!!!! This code was like this from beginning - this is student project. So, I am not even sure if this person cares about it at this time. Although, I will add the idea to my answer

Comment: @T.S. Nope I really dont care :) Thank you for all your answers:)